# webpack : import js lib & files

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I want import beyond_admin_panel_template js files in to the index.js and create index.bundle.js with webpack from them.

index.html file of admin-panel template that contained this scripts :

```
<!--Basic Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

    <!--Beyond Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/beyond.js"></script>


    <!--Page Related Scripts-->
    <!--Sparkline Charts Needed Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/charts/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/charts/sparkline/sparkline-init.js"></script>

    <!--Easy Pie Charts Needed Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/charts/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/charts/easypiechart/easypiechart-init.js"></script>

    <!--Flot Charts Needed Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/charts/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/charts/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/charts/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/charts/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/charts/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>

<script>
        // If you want to draw your charts with Theme colors you must run initiating charts after that current skin is loaded
        $(window).bind("load", function () {

            /*Sets Themed Colors Based on Themes*/
            themeprimary = getThemeColorFromCss('themeprimary');
            themesecondary = getThemeColorFromCss('themesecondary');
            themethirdcolor = getThemeColorFromCss('themethirdcolor');
            themefourthcolor = getThemeColorFromCss('themefourthcolor');
            themefifthcolor = getThemeColorFromCss('themefifthcolor');

            //Sets The Hidden Chart Width
            $('#dashboard-bandwidth-chart')
                .data('width', $('.box-tabbs')
                    .width() - 20);

            //-------------------------Visitor Sources Pie Chart----------------------------------------//
            var data = [
                {
                    data: [[1, 21]],
                    color: '#fb6e52'
                },
                {
                    data: [[1, 12]],
                    color: '#e75b8d'
                },
                {
                    data: [[1, 11]],
                    color: '#a0d468'
                },
                {
                    data: [[1, 10]],
                    color: '#ffce55'
                },
                {
                    data: [[1, 46]],
                    color: '#5db2ff'
                }
            ];
            var placeholder = $("#dashboard-pie-chart-sources");
            placeholder.unbind();

            $.plot(placeholder, data, {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        innerRadius: 0.45,
                        show: true,
                        stroke: {
                            width: 4
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            //------------------------------Visit Chart------------------------------------------------//
            var data2 = [{
                color: themesecondary,
                label: "Direct Visits",
                data: [[3, 2], [4, 5], [5, 4], [6, 11], [7, 12], [8, 11], [9, 8], [10, 14], [11, 12], [12, 16], [13, 9],
                [14, 10], [15, 14], [16, 15], [17, 9]],

                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    fill: true,
                    lineWidth: .1,
                    fillColor: {

... another code for initial all type of charts

    </script>
```

I install jquery with npm and create init.js file for `$(window).bind("load", function () {` script that exist in page but when try with `import` like this  :

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
import 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js';
...
import './init.js';
```

and serve with npm http-server or webpack-dev-server ,browser console give me this error :

> jquery undefine & $ undefine

and try with put this code on top of index.js file

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

but console give me last error

> jquery undefine & $ undefine

but when change

> import

to

> require

jquery undefine problem solved;but init.js not find reference function in import libs and initial charts

and console give me this error :

> getThemeColorFromCss function is undefine

my problem is how to import beyond_admin_panel_template js files in to the index.js and create index.bundle.js with webpack from them;

Comment: _"my js file "_ This is HTML.

Comment: yes this is index.html file of admin-panel that contained this script files